# Probability of observing the same value for 10th percentile in two different samples

Tags: r, probability, discrete-data

**Edited:**

I have a categorical variable comprising of values from 1 to 7 with these probability:

```
score   1        2       3      4       5       6   7
p       0.01    0.01    0.03    0.05    0.2   0.3   0.4
```

In two different samples from the two different populations, I found the same value for 10th percentile (i.e. 4) in observed data. I want to find the likelihood of having exactly the same value for 10th percentile.

FYI, the scores are answers to a scale and probabilities are proportions for each category in a normative sample.I want to be able to do this in R.

P.S.: any suggestion on calculating cumulative distribution of a variable with above-mentioned properties is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 'at least 10%', 'at most 10%' or 'exactly 10%'?

Comment: @Glen_b I meant exactly 10% but would be happy to learn other possibilities like 'at least 10%' and 'at most 10%'.

Comment: The proportion of times that exactly 1000 observations out of 10000 fall below 4 will be quite small (it's actually possible to compute this number, there's no need to simulate it).

Comment: @Glen_b The reason is that in a survey from two different samples from two different populations I found the same value for 10th percentile. I want to know how likely is to find the same value for 10th percentile in a variable.This is why I thought that a simulation would be proper.

Comment: Finding the same value for the 10th percentile is rather different from what you're asking about.

Comment: @Glen_b Actually I wasn't sure if I'm using the right term or not. Those probabilities are observed proportions in normative sample so I thought of using them as probabilities for observed values in samples.

Comment: Note that your first line (1-5) doesn't fit your table (1-7). To answer the original question as worded (take care with the phrasing of 'below 4'), you can evaluate the probability as `dbinom(1000,10000,.05)`. If you want to simulate it, you could use `rbinom`. Perhaps you could explain the original problem in more detail in your question.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks.I just edited the question.I'm not sure if we can use Binomial distribution for this data as the scores are for a variable with 7 categories. I also want to use those probabilites in my calculation.

Comment: The question you're answering is binomial, since an observation either falls in the required region or it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking the right question? Since you picked the value 4 only after seeing the data, wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask about the probability that the two cumulative distributions would be the same at one or more of the the first six score values? And wouldn't it be even more appropriate to ask about the probability that *some* such easily-noticeable feature of the two distributions would be the same?

Comment: @RayKoopman As I said to Glen_b, I'm not pretty sure about terminology. Your point could be also true about cumulative distributions but when the 10th percentile of two cumulative distribution is the same does it mean that the two cumulative distribution are the same?

Comment: @Glen_b Is there anyway to accommodate those probabilities and generate cumulative distribution?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182442/probability-of-getting-the-exact-same-letters-in-scrabble-2-turns-in-a-row

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem is intractable. This is because you *noticed* something odd and then want to find how likely it is. But you could have noticed anything else odd that happened. Thus, this is a problem of finding how likely a coincidence is, given that one happened.

However, if you want to pursue this further, Persi Diaconis has done some work on this, e.g. [Methods for Studying Coincidences](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/%7Efcale/CCC/DC.pdf)

Comment: It can be seen from this perspective as well. Indeed this coincidence given the fact that the two samples and population are different was surprising for me.

Comment: The link is dead, can you replace it?